# Input Menu Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, menu

So I'm making an input menu for my program which runs certain functions to display data depending on what the user inputs. The user must input selections in order; if the user selects 2 before 1 or 3 before 2 then the program should report an error. I had it working properly until I added in error strings which depicts what the user did wrong. Also, something that I hadn't figured out how to fix before was that when the wrong selection is inputed, the data generated before the selection must still be in play (ie. data generated in selection 1 must still be available for use if selection 3 is inputed instead, then selection 2 is used). However, my program doesn't emulate that. I was wondering if I could get some tips on how to modify my code.

Here is my code:

```
def menu():

    '''Displays menu for user and runs program according to user commands.'''
    prompt = """Select one of the following options: 
    1. Generate a new random dataset. 
    2. Calculate least squares for the dataset. 
    3. Calculate the Pearson Correlation Coefficient for the data set and 
    the estimate. 
    4. Quit.\nEnter your selection: """
    userInp = ""
    run = True
    while(run):

        userInp = input(prompt)    
        cond1 = False
        cond2 = False

        if userInp == '1':
            #function/program stuff
            cond1 = True
            print("Data Generated.\n")

        elif userInp == '2' and cond1:
            #function/program stuff
            cond2 = True

        elif userInp == '3' and cond1 and cond2:
            #function/program stuff

        elif userInp == '4':
            run = False

        else:
            error1 = "Error: no data generated yet"#                                 
            error2 = "Error: data generated but least squares not completed" 
            print(cond1 * error1 + cond2 * error2)
```

Note: I know that the stuff in the else statement doesn't quite work. It was a suggestion from a friend for shits and gigs. Wondering if I could get help on that too, but its not not necessary as I could probably figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically what is going on here is the `cond1` and `cond2` are resetting each time the `while(run):` block runs through.

I put your code in a sandbox, this is the fix (I modified the last else block as well):

```
   '''Displays menu for user and runs program according to user commands.'''
prompt = """
Select one of the following options: 
    1. Generate a new random dataset. 
    2. Calculate least squares for the dataset. 
    3. Calculate the Pearson Correlation Coefficient for the data set and the estimate. 
    4. Quit.\nEnter your selection: """
userInp = ""
run = True
cond1 = False
cond2 = False
while(run):

userInp = input(prompt)    

if userInp == '1':
    #function/program stuff
    cond1 = True
    print("Data Generated.\n")

elif userInp == '2' and cond1:
    #function/program stuff
    cond2 = True

elif userInp == '3' and cond1 and cond2:
    #function/program stuff

elif userInp == '4':
    run = False

else:
    error= ''
    if(not cond1):
        error = "Error: no data generated yet"#                                 
    elif(not cond2):
        error = "Error: data generated but least squares not completed" 
    print(error)
```